# Magento 2 Module License: Can I buy once and use modules on multiple instances?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-community, marketplace, licensing

I'm currently developing with magento2 and want to setup 4 instances of magento2:

1. Two local dev environments (two developers)
2. Dedicated Test Server
3. Production Server

When I buy a module from magento marketplace, can I install it on all four magento systems or do I have to buy the module four times?

Comment: once you purchased a module it's all yours you can use it as many times as you want.

Comment: @ASQ Totally depends on the licensing of the product, you can't use it everywhere in all cases.

Comment: Maybe it depends I am sharing my experience for community edition

Comment: thanks guys! Your answers and comments solve my question. So in most cases I'm good to go, but to be 100% clear I have to read the license terms of each extension carefully.

Comment: Exactly! In almost most cases you can get away with it, but licencing can be a tricky thing so thread with caution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only commercial use is the production server, then yes in most cases. 
But it all depends on the licencing of the product. In most cases there is a licence file in the plugin itself so your best bet is to check that